Can I access Adobe Acrobat's PDF-to-XLSX export feature from terminal?
I have a workflow that involves using Adobe Acrobat's built-in tool for exporting PDFs to Microsoft Excel Workbooks. I've experimented with several PDF-to-spreadsheet convertors, and this gives the best results for my purposes.
Because my workflow includes multiple PDF files that will update at various intervals, I would like to script the conversion step, rather than manually opening each PDF and clicking through the export menu.
I cannot figure out how to access Adobe export tools in a shell. Google is failing me, but I may not know the correct keywords. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Acrobat does have a command line options, but they are very limited.
However, there is a built-in batch processing function in the app itself, which can process multiple files.
https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/acrobat/using/action-wizard-acrobat-pro.html
